# analogRead values all over the place, while measuring light

Tags: adc, analogreference

I'm trying to detect light using an led that's already attached to the circuit. I have a flashlight shining on the led.

Minimal sketch:

```
while( true )
{
    int photoValue = 0;
    analogReference(INTERNAL);
    photoValue = analogRead(A5);

    Serial.println(photoValue);

    delay(300);

}
```

While I have my multimeter attached, it reads a pretty constant value around 5mV. The serial output however swings around, as seen in this sample output:

```
0
0
4
4
0
16
15
22
21
25
20
36
40
34
36
24
5
0
3
6
0
0
0
0
```

That would translate to values between 0 and 43mV.

When I disconnect the multimeter only get `1023` printed.

I don't get how the values from the ADC and the multimeter, totally don't match.

Comment: Can you show your circuit?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the LED isn't able to produce enough current to charge the S&H capacitor. Plus the LED, when not generating enough voltage, will most likely make it look like the pin is floating somewhat. You may need a high impedance buffer between the LED and the ADC.

Comment: In a few days I will have high impedance buffers available on eBay based around the OPA355. I will experiment with one when the components arrive to see what a difference it makes.

Comment: Not enough current; makes sense. The circuit is 8 LEDs in parallel, connected between gnd and A5. Tomorrow I'll try adding a small capacitor to the A5 pin. I don't have any room for something like an opamp. So if that doesn't work I'll just have to scrap this, nice to have, extra feature.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do, ultimately?

Comment: I have a string of tiny SMD LEDs attached to some fake eyelashes. I currently have a few different animations/patterns programmed. I thought it would be fun to make them more interactive, by e.g. turning the LEDs  on after camera flash is detected. Or just a regular increase in light hitting the LEDs, as camera flashes are very short. Pretty weird project but they look awesome when attached to a models eyelids.

Comment: That sounds fun! I'd love to see it when it's done. So I can imagine that space is at a premium. I can't imagine how / where you have stashed the Arduino... Does the model have a big hooter? ;)

Comment: The PCB is a 3 cm circle. ATMega328 on the front, CR2032 battery on the back, along with a hearclip. PCB will be placed on the back of the head, with wires going to the eyes. The wires are 0.1mm enameled copper. Here is [an older photo](http://gerben.algemeenbekend.nl/dump/eyelash.png). Final version will be two color (charlieplexed). Adding a 2.2nF capacitor (>100x the 13pF S&H capacitor) seems to stabilize at least a bit, though I haven't had much time to do some proper testing.

Comment: That is awesome! I love it! I expect to see it on the catwalks of London, Madrid and New York soon!

Comment: I have tested with an OPA355 and it improves things massively.

Comment: I printed the analogread values to the serial port. With the 2.2nF capacitor. You can see the voltage rising relatively slowly, when I point the flashlight on it. About a second. Removing the light does produce a sharp edge. Read values are still a bit is noisy, but I didn't put a cap on the aref pin in my pcb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the output of the LED is too high impedance for the ADC to work reliably.

Basically the LEDs can't produce enough current to charge the S&H capacitor properly, and on top of that the LED doesn't act as a resistive load when not forward biased, so the input is basically floating and picking up noise.

The best cure is to add a voltage-follower buffer with incredibly high input impedance in front of the ADC input.

By high impedance I mean something measured in the 10s to 100s of TΩ. Something like the OPA355.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. Due to the deadline I have to scrap the idea for now. But the next competition is in October, so maybe then. Anyway; much appreciated.